# How can i add the options of a REST call to a header as a parameter?

Tags: apache-camel, esb, blueprint-osgi

I am using an ESB to route data between SQL and REST calls. So far this is working fine, however when i want to add options to the REST call. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="placeholder"
             location="file:${karaf.home}/etc/nl.test.astron.sql.cfg" />


<restConfiguration bindingMode="json" component="servlet">
            <endpointProperty key="servletName" value="ASTRONServlet" />
        </restConfiguration>

        <rest path="/get/astrondata">
            <get uri="">            
                <to pattern="InOut" uri="direct:get" />         
            </get>
        </rest>

        <route id="get_to_uri">
            <from uri="direct:get"/>
            <setHeader headerName="boundRaMin">
                <simple>70</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="boundRaMax">
                <simple>90</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="boundDecMin">
                <simple>0</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="boundDecMax">
                <simple>30</simple>
            </setHeader>    
            <to uri="sql:{{sql.getDatabase}}?
                outputType=SelectList&amp;
                greedy=true&amp;
                useIterator=false"/>
        </route>
```

and the SQL code is:

```
sql.getDatabase=SElECT * FROM dbo.astron_data WHERE :#boundRaMin<ra AND 
                ra<:#boundRaMax AND :#boundDecMin<dec AND dec<:#boundDecMax
```

As one can see here, boundRaMin,boundRaMax,boundDecMin,boundDecMax are all set by in the headers, However i want to make these variable depending on the options defined in the rest call. Thus for example the following call:

http://localhost:8080/astron/get/astrondata?boundRaMin=value1&boundRaMax=value2&boundDecMin=value3&boundDecMax=value4

should fill the right values of value1...value4 into the headers. It seems that these query parameters do not get mapped to the headers.

Comment: What Camel version do you use? The query parameters in the URL ought to be mapped to Camel headers OOTB and this it should work. But are you saying it doesnt, if you remove all those hardcoded header values.

Comment: if i remove the hard coded headers i get the following error:

   org.apache.camel.RuntimeExchangeException: Cannot find key 
   [boundRaMin] in message body or headers to use when setting named 
   parameter in query [SElECT * FROM dbo.astron_data WHERE :? 
   boundRaMin<ra AND ra<:?boundRaMax AND :?boundDecMin<dec AND 
   dec<:?boundDecMax] on the exchange: Exchange[ID-WS0161-56531- 
  1545636863697-34-10][HttpMessage@0x39c61c91]

Comment: camel version is 2.16.5

Comment: To me it seems you are trying to define some default parameters to use in absence of providing explice values in the URI. Camel's REST-DSL [does support default values](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/rest-dsl.adoc#query-parameter-default-values) through defining parameters to the respective route definition. As Claus furthermore mentioned, both HTTP headers as well as query parameters will be copied to the inbound message headers automatically (if not prevented by a header filter strategy); this requires 2.17.0 at least though.

Comment: i installed camel 2.17 and this actually worked, thanks :D.

Answer (score 1):

According to camel-sql component, from Camel 2.14 onward you can use Simple expressions. Thus try to modify the property placeholder sql.getDatabase to the following:

```
sql.getDatabase=SELECT * FROM dbo.astron_data WHERE :${header.boundRaMin} < ra AND 
                ra < ${header.boundRaMax} AND ${header.boundDecMin} < dec AND dec < ${header.boundDecMax}
```